# Eclipse: SDL libraries cause undefined reference despite linking

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, sdl-2, mingw32

I'm trying to set up Eclipse with MinGW (32 bit version) as a compiler and including the SDL2 library(ies). Coming from Codeblocks I've had them running on my system already, but decided to switch to Eclipse. After extracting & linking the relevant libraries I can use functions from the SDL2 main library without errors. However, the additional libraries cause issues.

Here's the setup of my linker:
[linker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL3pZ.png)

Including the libraries as follows doesn't produce compiler errors:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
```

However, calling functions from the libraries does:
[undefined reference error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jctc0.png)

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:    C:\eclipse_workspace\sdl_final\Debug/../src/sdl_final.cpp:338: undefined reference to `TTF_Quit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\eclipse_workspace\sdl_final\Debug/../src/sdl_final.cpp:339: undefined reference to `IMG_Quit'
```

All MinGW files are in C:/MinGW. 
The header files (so, SDL_image.h , etc.) of SDL2 and additional libraries are in C:\MinGW\include\SDL2. 
The library files (libSDL2_image.a , etc.) are in C:\MinGW\lib.

The respective files in the "bin" directories of SDL and additional libraries  I've copied to System directory. (Win10, SysWOW64). I've also made sure that I'm using the 32bit SDL libraries.

I've absolutely no clue where the issue might be, especially since I can call functions from the SDL2 standard library just fine. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Libraries go in `lib`, not `include`, your library search path is wrong.

Comment: Did you compile SDL2 and SDL2_ttf yourself? If so, can you use `nm` to prove that `TTF_Quit` is present in `SDL2_ttf.dll`?

Comment: No, I haven't compiled them myself - I've them extracted unchanged from the respective archive files from the SDL sites.

Comment: You may have mixed up your MinGW code with libraries built for Visual Studio (VC). Download the MinGW development version of SDL2_ttf and try with that.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I redownloaded the files for both the SDL_2ttf and SDL2_image libraries (double checking they had mingw.tar.gz in their name) and replaced the old files and restarted Eclipse for good measure. The problem still persists, same error codes. I tried changing the Linkers library path to        "C:\MinGW\lib" too, same error codes.

Comment: Is it possible you have another SDL2_ttf.dll on your `$PATH` that was compiled for Visual Studio? You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to inspect the symbol names of any DLL you find. Also try switching your linker configuration to verbose so you know which DLL it attempts to link to.

Comment: No, I don't think that's possible - I just went through all the downloads I had in setting this up (as well for CodeBlocks earlier) and they're all the MinGW files, I've never set up a Visual Studio installation on this computer either.

Comment: Then it must be your linker picking up a DLL somewhere else. Try switching your linker to verbose, or ask `g++ -print-search-dirs` for the path. If my suspicion is correct you will find a SDL2_ttf.dll hiding in there somewhere.

Comment: Here's the log from --verbose on the linker: https://pastebin.com/6eBeJpp0 and here https://pastebin.com/CjZ1xUmB a log with -print-search-dirs as well. I (sadly) didn't see a folder structure in there that looks wrong

Comment: A clean install 'fixed' the issue - thank you for your patience and help!

Answer (score 0):

I did a clean install of MinGW, Eclipse and all aforementioned SDL2 libraries - one of these steps must have fixed the issue, though I couldn't pinpoint where it must have been. I suppose the most likely case is having extracted a 64 bit library by mistake where it should have been a 32 bit one.

Comment: Good to hear that!